# Redirect to home page after successful login using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I have a login page that works fine, but it doesn't redirect after the SESSION is set. I want my ajax to display errors if nessesary and redirect if the SESSION was set.

Here is my code:

```
AJAX:

<script>
        function loginUser(){
                         $.ajax({
                            type:"post",
                            url:"process.php",
                            data:$("#formsubmit").serialize(),
                            success:function(data){
                                if($session == true){
                                    window.location.href="http://www.example.com";    
                                }
                                $("#result").html(data);
                             }
                          });
                    }
    </script>

PHP:
if (sha1($passcheck) === $record['password']){
            $_SESSION['user']= $_POST['username'];
            mysqli_query($db_con, $updateIP);
            if($record['admin'] == 1){
                $_SESSION['admin1'] = $_POST['username'];
            }
        }else{
           echo "<font color='red'>Username or password was invalid.</font>";
      }
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    $session = true;
    echo $session;
}else{
    $session = false;
    echo $session;
}
?>
```

I did not include my whole PHP script or my whole HTML page, because the rest is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are trying to use the name of the php variable in your javascript to access the php response.

```
 success:function(data){
     if($session == true){
         window.location.href="http://www.example.com";    
     }
     $("#result").html(data);
 }
```

The variable `$session` isn't defined within the scope of the `success` function, thus `if($session == true)` will always return false, since `$session` will be `undefined`.

What ever your PHP code echos will be passed into the `success` function using the `data` param. Since your PHP code is just echoing either a 0 or 1 you would want to update the `if` line to `if(data == 1)`, or possibly even just `if (data)` since if the data variable is just 0 the it should return false, and if it's 1 then it should return true.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, when you set a variable to `true` and then echo it you get `1`
If you set it to `false` you get `0`.

You need to set `$session` to a string, instead of boolean.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    $session = 'true';
    echo $session;
}else{
    $session = 'false';
    echo $session;
}
```

And also change

```
if($session == 'true'){
    window.location.href="http://www.example.com";    
}
```